# How To Hover shapes over text to "reveal" in p5.js? similar to clipping masks?

Tags: p5.js

I have multiple rectangles that move with mouse events. I want those rectangles to reveal text, like a moving cutout. However, I only see tutorials for images. I'm a novice but it seems like this should be way easier!!

```js
let myMask;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  //myMask=createGraphics(400, 400);
  //ctx= myMask.canvas.getContext("2d")
  let x1= map(mouseX, 0, 400, 100, 300);
  let x2= map(mouseX, 0, 400, -200, 600);
  //myMask.
  rect(mouseX, 150, 600+mouseX, 50);
 // ctx.clip();
  //myMask.text('what do', 200, 160);
  //text(myMask, 200, 160);
  rect(x1, 215, 400+mouseX, 50)
  rect(x2, 280, 600+mouseX, 50);
}
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

I was trying to follow tutorials, but these are my rectangles and I want lines of text to appear "underneath", within the rectangles.

I've looked into how to do it with images and can't find it for text.

Comment: To clarify, by reveal text, you're asking that when the rectangles move to the right ("off-screen"), you want text to be underneath them? Or are you wanting text to be inside the rectangle and move with it?

Comment: It sounds like this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70807530/how-to-penetrate-or-cut-holes-through-a-2d-foreground/70809719#70809719 is that the case?